# Telerik Reporting - Dynamic

Tags: telerik-reporting, dynamic-reports

In telerik reporting, is this possible to bind my data dynamically from database with space and special characters in telerik table column name? is there any alternate solution?

Comment: please show example of table column name, discuss how you would like ti to show up in report - what it should look like, preferably you have already tried something that does what you want and it didn't work, so describe that if so.  otherwise this is too vague a question and too open to opinions to elicit lots of high quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Reporting supports referencing the fields whose names contain spaces and special chars like that (sample expression):

```
=Fields.[My field'name]
```

You can also reference fields dynamically passing the name of the field using the Fields function (for example, pass the name using a report parameter):

```
=Fields(Parameters.FieldName.Value)
```